# Evaluate minimal storage disk size with Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark-sql

I'm performing an analysis/comparison between different Parquet schemas and different Cassandra table layouts.

One of the output is the storage size on disk.

I want to make sure that I am fair to Cassandra and so I want to make sure that snapshots are deleted and that compaction is run "completely".

My data are initially in Parquet, I read it with Spark SQL, have a big data frame which I then write to C* using the Spark-Cassandra Connector.

What type of "command" should I run (with `nodetool` I assume) to delete the snapshots, run the compaction and then get a precise number on the disk size of my table?

Answer (score 1):

You have to execute `nodetool clearsnapshot`.

This commands removes snapshots in the node pointed by `nodetool` command only. So you have to do it on each nodes.

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/tools/toolsClearSnapShot.html

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/operations/opsBackupDeleteSnapshot.html?hl=clearsnapshot

Comment: Thanks, indeed that for the first step. How do I make sure compaction is all done? As easy as running `nodetool compactionstats`?

Comment: The only way to be sure compaction is all done is to execute `nodetool compact` command.